# In JAXRS apply a container request interceptor to a specific provider only

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

With JAXRS-2.0 (Jersey 2.2, specifically) I'm trying to apply a request interceptor to a specific resource provider class (which is in a 3rd party library), and I'm obviously doing it wrong. I am getting the error below - I'm a bit baffled as to the cause. The net effect is that the interceptor is being invoked on every request to every provider instead of the 1 provider. This is the error:

> 2017-11-26 10:43:51.061
>   [localhost-startStop-1][WARN][o.g.j.server.model.ResourceMethodConfig]
>   - The given contract (interface javax.ws.rs.container.DynamicFeature) of class com.idfconnect.XYZ provider cannot be bound to a resource
>   method.

The interceptor class is defined as:

```
@Provider
public class XYZ implements WriterInterceptor, DynamicFeature {
```

In my ResourceConfig I'm registering the interceptor for the specific provider as follows (I suspect this is where I've gone astray):

```
@ApplicationPath("service")
public class MyApp extends ResourceConfig {
  public MyApp() {
    ResourceConfig rc = register(SomeThirdPartyResource.class);
    rc.register(XYZ.class);
    ...
```

Can someone help me figure out how to bind the interceptor to *SomeThirdPartyResource* class only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't make your provider implement `DynamicFeature`. This is probably the cause of the warning. You are trying to register the interceptor, which is also a `DynamicFeature`, and Jersey is telling you that `DynamicFeature` is not something that is supposed to be registered to a method.

You should make a separate class for the `DynamicFeature` and inside the `configure` check for the resource you want to attach your provider to (using the `ResourceInfo`, then register it accordingly. For example

```
class XYZ implements DynamicFeature {
    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo info, FeatureContext ctx) {
       if (info.getResourceClass().equals(ThirdPartyResource.class) {
           ctx.register(YourWriterImplementation.class);
           // or
           ctx.register(new YourWriterImplementation());
       }
    }
}
```

The reason you are getting all the resources hit by the interceptor is because you are registering the interceptor with the `ResourceConfig`. This will attach it all resources. You only want to register the `DynamicFeature` and let it determine which resource to tie to.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! I split the DynamicFeature into a separate class from the interceptor provider and now all is well